# Delphi & ADO: datetime to string conversion

Tags: delphi, date, ado

I use Delphi 2006 and ADO to connect to a MS Access database. Some of the fields I retrieve are Date fields (in Access formatted as "Medium Date" i.e. 20-Apr-2010) however I have to retrieve them as Strings:

```
FValue:=FAccessADOQuery.Fields.FieldByName(FIELD_NAME).AsString;
```

and then the fields are formatted as follows: 4/20/2010.

My question is: when does this formatting take place and how can I customize it? Is it ADO settings (could not find anything there) or the OS (I use Win XP ENG with US locale)? Or maybe it's Delphi?

Thanks!
Lou

Comment: If you are getting 4/20/2010, that is what the user's regional settings asks for. This will be the same as the detailed view in Windows Explorer. Ideally you should honour (or honor) the settings, unless you are creating input for another system that expects a particular format. The regional settings are set up in the "Regional and Language" section of the control panel (in XP). However there is a known bug in Win7 that causes problems with this. Refer http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2010/03/19/9980203.aspx

Answer (score 2):

the [`ShortDateFormat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.ShortDateFormat) and [`LongTimeFormat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.LongTimeFormat) variables are used to format an TDateTimeField to string.

you can change the value of theses variables or try something different like this :

```
Dt :TDateTime;
Ds :String;
begin
//FAccessADOQuery.Fields.FieldByName(FIELD_NAME).AsString
Dt:=FAccessADOQuery.Fields.FieldByName(FIELD_NAME).AsDateTime;
Ds:=FormatDateTime('dd-mmm-yyyy',dt);
end;
```

Comment: I think the order of the parameters of FormatDateTime function was wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just found it. It's delphi general settings (if missing then the values are taken from the OS):

```
DateSeparator   := '-';
ShortDateFormat := 'dd-mmm-yyyy';
```

And now the returned value is "20-Apr-2010".

Answer (score 0):

You can retreive the Value as DateTime and use this function to convert it to your format

`FValue:=FAccessADOQuery.Fields.FieldByName(FIELD_NAME).AsDateTime;`

```
function DateToMediumDate(const Date: TDate): string;
var
  y, m, d: Word;
begin
  DecodeDate(Date, y, m , d);

  Result := Format('%d-%s-%d', [d, ShortMonthNames[m], y]);
end;
```