# Converting from SQL Date to DateTime in Delphi XE

Tags: sql-server, delphi, date, datetime, delphi-xe

I've searched google and SO with no usable fixes for this. I am retrieving a `date` from a table in SQL Server. I need to convert this to a `DateTime` object in Delphi. The problem seems to lie in the value coming in from SQL. The version of SQL Server on which I am testing this is SQL Server 2012 (not R2).

If I display the value retrieved from a query as a string I get:

```
myQuery.FieldByName('ActiveDate').AsString;
```

I get the value

```
2014-06-15
```

`myQuery` is a TADOQuery type.

DateTime doesn't seem to like this format since all of these fail:

```
myQuery.FieldByName('ActiveDate').AsDateTime;
StrToDateTime(myQuery.FieldByName('ActiveDate').AsString);
StrToDate(myQuery.FieldByName('ActiveDate').AsString);
```

The failure message from the caught exception that gets logged is:

```
''2014-06-15'' is not a valid date and time
```

Is there a solution to this that doesn't involve a complicated string manipulation and that would not be affected by the locale of the server?

Comment: What is the `myQuery` component ? What is the data type of the `ActiveDate` field and which version of SQL Server do you use ?

Comment: How about a solution involving really simple string manipulation? In order to do that you need to specify the format precisely.

Comment: See [Delphi SQL Date reading issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14922339/576719).

Comment: And what do you mean by "all of these fail"? How do they fail?

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357822/delphi-ado-datetime-to-string-conversion {DateSeparator   := '-';
ShortDateFormat := 'dd-mmm-yyyy';}

Comment: @TLama I've edited the original post with clarifications.

Comment: @JerryDodge I've edited the original post with clarifications

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What did you have in mind? My experience with Delphi is limited, I am maintaining legacy code. Normally I work in .NET.

Comment: @JayDee I saw that same post earlier but what I saw was all from an established datetime object converting to a string. I am trying to do the opposite. Can you specify a format when converting from a string to a datetime in delphi?

Comment: Do you really have two sets of quotes in your string?  That would certainly make the function break.

Comment: What is the definition of the field in the MySQL Table?

Comment: @JerryDodge no that's just how the log format is set up. The value that comes back from `myQuery.FieldByName('ActiveDate').AsString` is `2014-06-15` without quotes.

Comment: @JayDee It's SQL Server 2012 and it is a `date` field.

Comment: Do you mean that reading e.g. `dt := myQuery.FieldByName('ActiveDate').AsDate;` (dt is TDateTime) raises an exception or what?

Comment: I suspect your query is not returning a date, but is using `CONVERT()` to change the date column to a string, in which case you have no choice but to parse it. The easiest solution is to simply remove the `CONVERT` from the SQL and just return the date itself, and then you can use it however you need in a front-end application (like your Delphi app).

Comment: I'm with @Ken. Or maybe you created persistent fields at design time for `myQuery`, and `ActiveDate`  is set as `TStringField`...

Comment: @kobik I am on XE (1) and it doesn't seem to recognize `.AsDate`. If I try to do `dt := myQuery.FieldByName('ActiveDate').AsDateTime;` it throws a `EConvertError` with the message `''2014-06-15'' is not a valid date and time`. I am not sure why double single quotes are included but the `AsString` value is `2014-06-15` and so is the value of the date in SQL.

Comment: @mvanella AsDate is a red herring. How did you write your query or declare your fields?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `myQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM Alerts')` It has a where clause that compares some date fields to NOW but I'm leaving it out here unless its absolutely necessary for a solution, which I don't believe it is.

Comment: Since you don't know how to solve your problem, why do you feel able to decide what is or is not helpful to answerers. When someone like Ken asks about your query, you would do well to listen.

Comment: I'm happy in this thread thank you. I was offering advice. Take it or leave it. My spider sense tells me that when you reveal more about how the query and fields are set up then you'll be able to avoid strings altogether which is what you want to do.

Comment: @KenWhite I don't see any converts in the code, it's just a simple declaration. `queryString := 'SELECT * FROM Alerts WHERE ActiveDate <= CAST(:Now1 AS DATE) AND ExpirationDate > CAST(:Now2 AS DATE)';`

Comment: @KenWhite continuing: The string is added to the query using SQL.Add and then parameters are added for `Now1` and `Now2`: `myQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('Now1').Value := DateTimeToIso8601(Today);`

Comment: Why do you need DateTimeToIso8601? That indicates that the underlying column is not a SQL Server DateTime/DateTime2 column, but a string instead (which would explain the extraneous quote characters you're getting). What is the actual data type of the ActiveDate column? (By actual, I mean the actual SQL data type that was used in the CREATE TABLE statement, not what it looks like if you do a SELECT.)

Comment: @KenWhite the CREATE TABLE statement is just declaring it as a `date`. There is no conversion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I could reproduce this behavior (SQL Server 2008 R2).
SQL-Server data type `date` (2008+) maps to `TWideStringField` (`ftWideString`) with ADO provider `SQLOLEDB.1`.

Accessing this field (`TWideStringField`) with `.AsDateTime` will raise an exception as described in the quesion:
`'2014-06-15' is not a valid date and time`.

Here is a related (or duplicate?) question:
[Delphi 6, ADO, MS database “Date” field is same as ftWideString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356578/delphi-6-ado-ms-database-date-field-is-same-as-ftwidestring)

Possible solutions:

- use the SQL-Server native client e.g. `Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;` -> `date` is mapped to `TDateField`
- `SELECT` via `CAST(ActiveDate AS datetime)` and then `.AsDateTime` works as expected.
- use `datetime` data type on SQL-Server instead of `date`
- access the `date` field via [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25247506/937125) provided by @Chris Thornton

Answer (score 6):

Here's a function that should do the trick, thanks to feedback from David and Remy:

```
function AnsiDateStrToDate(AnsiDate : string) : TDate;
// Convert data in YYYY-MM-DD to TDate
var
  Fmt : TFormatSettings; // Does not need to be freed
begin
  Fmt := TFormatSettings.Create;
  Fmt.ShortDateFormat := 'YYYY-MM-DD';
  Fmt.DateSeparator := '-';
  result := StrToDate(AnsiDate,Fmt);
end;
```

Usage:

```
if AnsiDateStrToDate(myQuery.FieldByName('ActiveDate').AsString) = Date Then
  writeln('Today!')
Else
  writeln('Not Today!);
```

Comment: If you must do this, use conversion functions that don't depend on global state. The overloads that accept a format settings parameter. But surely it's better to avoid converting to string at all.

Comment: In other words the question is really about how to read a `date` field without using any string conversions. If possible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Agreed. IMO, if you need it to be a date, use .AsDate instead of .AsString.

Comment: So write that in the answer. Problem is, SQL date types aren't understood that way. Which is the essence of the question.

Comment: The global formatting variables are not thread-safe, and have been completely removed in XE6.  If you are going to use `FormatSettings`, the *correct* way is to use the overloaded version of `StrToDate()` that takes a `TFormatSettings` as input: `Fmt := TFormatSettings.Create; Fmt.ShortDateFormat := 'YYYY-MM-DD'; Fmt.DateSeparator := '-'; ... := StrToDate(myQuery.FieldByName('ActiveDate').AsString, Fmt);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, good point about not being thread-safe.  But DXE6 definitely does understand SysUtils.FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat.  Anyway, I will take your advice on the overloaded StrToDate.

Comment: Is `.AsDate` supposed to be available before XE2? I am running XE1 and it doesn't recognize it: `'TField' does not contain a member named 'AsDate'` I couldn't find it in Embarcadero's documentation pre-XE2: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DB.TParam.AsDate

Comment: @Chris Remy is giving the exact same advice I did. You absolutely need to fix the answer.

Comment: @mvanella Ah well, I guess I should not have deleted my answer if I'd known you wanted a text processing based solution. I don't understand why you don't want to get to the bottom of this. Does it not concern you that you've no idea where this date formatting comes from? What happens if on some other machine it comes back with a different format? Until you actually know where this text comes from, I cannot see how you can proceed.

Comment: @davidheffernan Feel free to submit an answer and I will look it over. I never asked you to delete yours, that was all you. :)

Comment: You already saw my answer. It wasn't very good. I think you really need to be trying to understand where this string comes from.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Switching locales a few times didn't seem to change the result, no errors were introduced. I am a little curious as to why that value is coming in weird, and I think Ken gave me some things to look into. But for now this question has gotten a little out of hand so I think I'd like to keep it simple. Also, you are an unpleasant individual with which to interact so I'd prefer to keep that interaction to a minimum. Regardless, thank you for your help.

Comment: Why is it unpleasant? I'm giving you my advice. It's up to you what you do with it. Surely you came here for advice. I don't like to see problems closed when they have not been properly solved. I find that frustrating.

Comment: @mvanella I'm happy now. Kobik's answer addresses the root problem quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, this answer is slightly tangential but extends from the response from Chris Thornton (which itself was a little off topic).

As has been indicated, versions of Delphi before XE6, the dateTimeFormat routines are not thread safe.  Also in versions of Delphi before Delphi 6 (or maybe 7), the TFormatSetting is not available either.

For versions of Delphi before the existence of TFormatSettings AND if you don't mind being thread Unsafe, you can use this routine.

```
function AnsiDateStrToDate(AnsiDate : string) : TDateTime;
// Convert data in YYYY-MM-DD to TDate
// WARNING NOT THREAD SAFE
var
  lFmt_dateSeparator : char;
  lFmt_ShortDateFormat: string;
begin
  lFmt_dateSeparator := DateSeparator;
  lFmt_ShortDateFormat := ShortDateFormat;
  try
    ShortDateFormat := 'YYYY-MM-DD';
    DateSeparator := '-';
    result := StrToDate(AnsiDate);
  finally
     DateSeparator := lFmt_dateSeparator;
     ShortDateFormat := lFmt_ShortDateFormat;
  end
end;
```

I have also done a re-implementation below which is general. Works with wide or ansi strings, supports time and is thread safe (but a little long-winded!).

```
function SQLDateStrToDate(ASQLDate : string) : TDateTime;
// Convert String in YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS.ZZZ to TDatetime
// in Delphi XE6 and previous format strings are not thread safe
// in Delphi 5 and lower, TFormatSettings are not available
// so this is threadsafe, if a little inelegant;
var
  lDate, lTime :string;
  p,c : integer;
  y,d,m,h,n,s,z : word;
begin
  result := 0;
  p := Pos('-',ASQLDate);
  if p<1 then exit;
  lDate := trim(ASQLDate);
   // Time and Date separation
  p := pos(' ',lDate);
  lTime := '';
  if (p>0) then
  begin
    lTime := copy(lDate,p+1,MaxInt);
    lDate := copy(lDate,1,p-1);
  end;
  p := pos('-',lDate);

  // Date must be of the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'
  if (p<>5) then exit;
  Val(Copy(lDate,1,4),y,c);
  if c<1 then
  begin
    Val(Copy(ldate,6,2),m,c);
    if c<1 then Val(Copy(ldate,9,2),d,c);
    Result := EncodeDate(y,m,d);
  end;

  // Time must be 24hr
  p := pos(':',lTime);
  if (p<1) then exit;
  h:=0; n:=0; s:=0; z:=0;
  Val(copy(lTime,1,p-1),h,c);
  if c<1 then
  begin
     Val(copy(lTime,4,2),n,c);
     if c>0 then exit;
     Val(copy(lTime,7,2),s,c);
     p := pos('.',lTime);
     if p>0 then Val(copy(lTime,p+1,3),z,c);
     Result := result + EncodeTime(h,n,s,z);
   end;
end;
```